# Finding maximum of Nth elements of a list of lists in C#

Tags: c#, linq, max, nested-lists

I have a list of lists in C#, where each sublist has three doubles, representing a 3D point:

```
{{x1, y1, z1},
 {x2, y2, z2},
 {x3, y3, z3}}
```

I want to find the 3D bounding box of this dataset, and that means finding minimum X, maximum X, minimum Y, maximum Y, etc.

With Python/Numpy, I would get it with, say, `zmax = list_of_lists[:,2].max()`, etc.

Is there an elegant way to do this in C#? I suspect Linq is the way to go, but I haven't understood how it works yet (if some answer includes Linq, please explain how it works, please :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in C# with LINQ, like this:

```
var orig = new List<List<double>>();
var maxX = orig.Select(pt => pt[0]).Max();
var maxY = orig.Select(pt => pt[1]).Max();
var maxZ = orig.Select(pt => pt[2]).Max();
```

The way this works in LINQ is that the list of points is traversed, for each point, the requested coordinate is selected, and then the `Max` is computed. There is also a `Min` function to get you the other corner of the bounding box.

This is somewhat suboptimal, because the list is traversed multiple times. A pair of nested loops would probably do the same thing more efficiently, while remaining just as readable:

```
var min = new List<double>{double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue};
var max = new List<double>{double.MinValue, double.MinValue, double.MinValue};
foreach (var point in orig) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i != 3 ; i++) {
        min[i] = Math.Min(min[i], point[i]);
        max[i] = Math.Max(max[i], point[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Except for the different dadatype (easily adaptable to my problem) this seems to be what I was looking for. Should the downvote be removed if the answer is edited? I believe it should be `orig.Select(pt => pt[0]).Max()`, isn't it?

Comment: @Clint Fair enough, this is fixed now.

Comment: (as for the second solution: since my lists are relatively small, I'll go with the more compact and readable solution, the actual performance difference would be negligible in my case).

Comment: Accepted for legibility and compactness.

Comment: There's no need for both a `Select` and a `Max`.  `Max` takes a selector.

Comment: @Servy I picked a solution that best mimics OP's `list_of_lists[:,2].max()` example. While `orig.Max(pt => pt[0])()` is shorter and perhaps even a bit faster, it hides the inner workings of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create your list like this, possibly use a specific class for 3D points rather than tuples if you require more functionality.

```
var points = new[] {
    Tuple.Create(x1, y1, z1),
    Tuple.Create(x2, y3, z2),
    Tuple.Create(x3, y3, z3)
};
```

Then, like @dasblinkenlight writes, you can use linq to select `Max()` or `Min()`:

```
var maxX = points.Select(pt => pt.Item1).Max();
```

Or even shorter:

```
var maxX = points.Max(pt => pt.Item1);
```

---

**Edit**: A simple class for ease of use:

```
class Point3D {
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }
}

var points = new[] {
    new Point3D(x1, y1, z1),
    new Point3D(x2, y3, z2),
    new Point3D(x3, y3, z3)
};

var maxX = points.Max(pt => pt.X);
```

Comment: There is already a `System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D` class (very hidden, and very useful... ;o)

Comment: I found the existing `Point3D` when I put the Google to your answer but decided to write one anyway since it's in `PresentationCore.dll` which you're not likely to have referenced. But it's good to have it mentioned here anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Xaruth Why would you ever use `Tuple` when there is already a class built into the system that represents exactly what your object represents?  You gain improved type safety, clearer meaning of what the instance represents based on the type name to others, you get appropriate property names, etc.  What advantage does `Tuple` have?

Comment: I think `Tuple` is great for doing some quick stuff, but often still prefer proper classes for readability of the property names.

Comment: @Servy In this particular case (3 doubles making a point), you can use Point3D. But, in general way, you can do more with Tuple, as it is not limited to 3 elements and double type. The Tuple solution still good if the question is "i have n element of type x".

Comment: @Xaruth If you have an unknown number of solutions of the same type then you should be using a collection, which is the "I have N elements of type X" case.  For the "I have a fixed number of objects of a fixed type" you should generally use a custom type representative of what that object represents.

Answer (score 0):

If all elements are of the same type and the property you're interested in is named, say, `Z`, you can do this:

```
var max = list_of_points.Max(p => p.Z);
```

In your case, since you seem to be using a `double[][]`, you can do this:

```
var max = list_of_lists.Max(p => p[0]);
```

So the full bounding box would be defined by two points, like this:

```
var topLeft = new double[] 
{
    list_of_lists.Min(p => p[0]),
    list_of_lists.Min(p => p[1]),
    list_of_lists.Min(p => p[2])
};
var bottomRight = new double[] 
{
    list_of_lists.Max(p => p[0]),
    list_of_lists.Max(p => p[1]),
    list_of_lists.Max(p => p[2])
};
```

However, this requires you to make 6 passes through the list (one for each coordinate for each point). You can do this for some performance improvement:

```
var topLeft = list_of_lists.Aggregate((s, p) => return double[] { Math.Min(s[0], p[0]), Math.Min(s[1], p[1]), Math.Min(s[2], p[2]) });
var bottomRight = list_of_lists.Aggregate((s, p) => return double[] { Math.Max(s[0], p[0]), Math.Max(s[1], p[1]), Math.Max(s[2], p[2]) });
```

This would make only 2 passes through the list.

*NOTE:* The same code can be done with `List<List<double>>` rather than `double[][]` by simply adding `.ToList()` after each array declaration.

Comment: This answer assumes this is a list of lists of point objects, the op seems to be using a list of three coordinates as his point object.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore Like most people that answered here, I misunderstood OP's question initially. I updated my answer to be more applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really a `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerables` of doubles with always the same order of X, Y, Z, then you could do something like this:

```
var list = new []
            {
                new [] { 1, 2, 3 },
                new [] { 4, 5, 6 },
                new [] { 7, 8, 9 }
            };
var maxX = list.Select(s => s.Skip(0).Take(1)).Max();
var minY = list.Select(s => s.Skip(1).Take(1)).Min();
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you taken a look at the SelectMany linq operator? I think it may be helpful for your problem.

Comment: The OP indicated that he is not very conversant with LINQ - an example would help.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan agreed, but providing examples and answers can be counterproductive, by forcing him to look up the operator he may discover something else or learn something beyond what I would have given him.

Comment: First, this is not an answer.  It's at best, a comment.  Second, it's almost certainly not helpful.  He wants the max of each column, flattening the list removes the ability to determine whether a value represents an X, Y, or Z value.